# Web API Returns Wrong Values after being Published to IIS

Tags: entity-framework, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, iis-10

Please help me. The API I created works fine when I launch it with Visual Studio but (the POST methods) has issues I deployed to IIS. 
It returns wrong values and sometimes, null values. If i go back to test it in debug mode it works well.

**THIS IS WHERE I'M CALLING THE API**

```
try
            {
                string apiToken = "DEFAULTAPI";

                EmployeeObject EmployeeObject = new EmployeeObject()
                {
                    username = "John Doe"
                    password = "12345"
                    apiToken = apiToken
                };

                var emp = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(EmployeeObject);
                string url = "http://localhost/PublishVersion/api/Company";
                //the url variable holds the published version link
                var response = client.PostAsync(url, new StringContent(emp, Encoding.UTF8, "application/json"));
                response.Wait();
                var result = response.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    Uri employeeUrl = result.Headers.Location;
                    var statusMessage = result.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                    if (statusMessage == "yes")
                    {
                        status = true;
                    }
                    else if (statusMessage == "no")
                    {
                        status = false;
                    }
                }
                return status;
            }
```

**AND THIS IS THE API**

```
public string Post([FromBody] Employees employees)
    {
        string message = "no";
        if (employees != null)
        {
            string emp = employees.username;
            string password = employees.password
            string apiToken = employees.apiToken
            APIToken token = _dbContext.MyTable.Where(x => x.apitoken == apitoken).FirstOrDefault();
            //APIToken is a table which has properties company and boss (both string)
             if (token != null)
             {
               string company = token.company;
               string boss = token.boss;

               return message = "yes" + " " + company + "" + boss;
             }
             else
             {
               return message = "invalid token";
             }
        }

        return message + employee.username;
    }
```

The api returns "no John Doe" to the caller, which shouldn't be that way, since it displayed the username value which shows that the employee object is not null. Why doesn't it go into the block of code since it passed the null check? This issue only comes up when I deploy the API project to the IIS (version 10). Works fine in Visual Studio debug mode.

Also, the API and Winsform(where i'm calling it from) are on the same machine.

Thank you.

Comment: The parameter of the method is called `employee` whereat you access `employees` to create the response. If this is not a typo, could you please share where `employee` is defined?

Comment: There are significant differences, https://blog.lextudio.com/web-application-differences-in-visual-studio-and-iis-60fec7e311b3 so you need to check if your database responds the same.

Comment: @LexLi what do you mean by significant differences?

Comment: According to your description, I suggest you could try to use remote debug to debug the application to see why it doesn't return the right value. The remote debug could directly debug the application which has hosted on the IIS. More details about how to remote debug it, you could refer to below [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59916281/web-api-returns-wrong-values-after-being-published-to-iis).

Comment: okay it is working now. I used remote debugging and found out that Apitoken table was not granted select access in the database. Thanks guys.